# Prism 4/Silverlight 4/MEF - Region not found

Tags: silverlight, prism

I'm just learning PRISM so may be this is very simple error: I'm trying to define Region in 'Style' and they not found :( :(

On main 'Shell' window I have 'ContentControl' that include 'Frame' object. The 'ContentControl' styled in attached ResourceDictionary and all Regions defined there (with additional Colors, Brushes, Buttons, Grids, etc...) But whenever program runs (all correctly shown on screen) the IRegionManager.Regions is empty collection....

Is there anything I can do to use regions from 'Style' ???

This is the code:

Shell.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="CardManagment.Shell"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Style="{StaticResource MainWindowStyle}">
        <sdk:Frame x:Name="MainFrame"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   BorderBrush="#FFFB0000"
                   Style="{StaticResource GlobalNavigationFrameStyle}"
                   UriMapper="{StaticResource GlobalUriMapper}" />
    </ContentControl>
</UserControl>
```

and ResourceDictionary:

```
     <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism" 
        xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit">
            <Style x:Key="MainWindowStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#FFDC1EBA">
        <ContentControl x:Name="GlobalLogoRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="GlobalLogoRegion" />
    </Border>
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - for now I found an answer on this page: [Regions inside DataTemplates in Prism v4 using a region behavior](http://blogs.southworks.net/dcherubini/2011/11/10/regions-inside-datatemplates-in-prism-v4-using-a-region-behavior/)

Actually it's a known bug in PRISM according to this article.